# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'foo' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

From what I've seen on the other posts this error is because the parameter given in the method signature didn't match the posted input name. Or that somehow the value isn't even sent.

First of all this page is a test page to log onto Facebook. it retrieves the uid and the access token for a user and then sends that to the server to be stored in session and redirected to another page. All the javascript was taken from the C# FB sdk and the server side is pretty basic.

The real issue I'm confused on is that it runs correctly if I'm logged in as my own account on FB but a test-user, not a friend a temp test-user account generated by the API, produces this error after the pop up asks for the user to give the app permissions. I looked at the form data right before it is submitted and it has hidden inputs with the corresponding names and values to my parameters on the server.

Any idea why it would not send the foo variable through the post with the test user?

EDIT: here is the javascript that works correctly for my account, fails to send uid for test user. I renamed some of the query string parameters but

```
var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

// Do a post to the server to finish the logon
// This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
form.setAttribute("action", 'BAR>');

var tField = document.createElement("input");
tField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
tField.setAttribute("name", 'RAHR');
tField.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
form.appendChild(tField);

var uField = document.createElement("input");
uField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
uField.setAttribute("name", 'foo');
uField.setAttribute("value", uid);
form.appendChild(uField);

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();

//Server side
public ActionResult BAR(string RAHR, int foo)
```

Comment: It's really hard to know what's going on when you've given no code.

Comment: Well, it is hard to say something without code but your error message says, you should change your `foo` type `int` to `int?`. `int` does not allow `null` value.

Comment: Right, I didn't think the code would help because the error happens when it hands the data to the method. The method accepts a string and an int and neither can be null. I don't want them to be null.
 I'll add the javascript but its copied from the C# fb sdk.

Comment: Ahh foo was too large for the int parameter. Strange that is comes in as null instead of overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the value coming in was too large. Causing the int parameter to overflow and instead of giving a strange value MVC nulled it out instead I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Replace you method from --> public ActionResult BAR(string RAHR, int foo)
to --> public ActionResult BAR(string RAHR, int? foo)